# SSRS Truncate text rather than soft return

Tags: reporting-services

Normally, in an SSRS textbox.

*If the amount of content takes up too much space it will move to the next line to display all of the contents of the textbox*

My desired case:

*If the amount of content takes up too much space it will truncate the rest of the content*

Is there a way too accomplish this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Go to the properties of the object and set `Can Grow` to false